# Finding and replacing a line in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script to login to remote servers, find a powershell script, find a line in that script and update/replace the same with another.

```
$psscript = 'D:\myscript.psm1'

$boxNametoreplace = "$boxName = 'currentbox443.org'"
$boxNamereplacedby = "$boxName = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($Null).HostName"

(Get-Content $psscript).replace($boxNametoreplace, $boxNamereplacedby) | Set-Content $psscript
```

This script does replace it but it skills the $Null so it basically replaced it as

```
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName().HostName
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: In short: Inside `"..."`, to treat `$` characters _literally_ (rather than as the start of a variable reference or subexpression to interpolate), you must escape them as `\`$`. If your string value _as a whole_ is to be taken literally, use `'...'` quoting instead, which requires no escaping. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally want the text on that line to become :

$boxName = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($Null).HostName

then you need to use single quotes rather than double, eg :

```
$boxNamereplacedby = '$boxName = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($Null).HostName'
```

With double quotes PowerShell will expand any variables found within the string, which is why $Null effectively disappears, while single quotes don't do variable expansion and will leave the text as specified.

That also means that $boxName doesn't get changed which you've not mentioned. If you want that expanded but not $Null then the alternative would be to stick with double quotes, but assign the $Null string as :

```
$strNull='$Null'    
$boxNamereplacedby = "$boxName = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($strNull).HostName"
```

which then causes both variables in the line to be expanded, but $strNull expands to become the $Null value you're after.